How to simulate a uniform distribution around zero in LTSpice?
I am using LTSpice for a Monte-Carlo simulation, I typically use the function {mc(x,y)} for componant variability
I also want to introduce spread in the feedback pin voltage of a DCDC converter by adding a series voltage source:

This obviously does not work as it is multiplying zero with a tolerance.
How would you induce a uniform distribution around zero?

Not sure how you could get much more elegant than two extra characters. You might want to be DRY and replace the 1's with a parameter!

Agreed. Your solution is very elegant. I would edit the solution out and post it as the answer. It’s a worthwhile question to have an accepted answer for.

Ok, I will, thanks!


This works, the tolerance is directly in Volts (flat distribution of +/- 10 mV in that case)
(For the copy-paste: {mc(1,tol)-1} )
